# How to make a custom validation for a form using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

so i need to make validation for a form. the form need to have the value of 1 - 6 and there cannot be a duplicate.

so i make a temporary variable to record all the data kind of like this

```
let temporary = []

temporary[document.getElementById('needs_1').value-1] = 'needs 1';
temporary[document.getElementById('needs_2').value-1] = 'needs 2';
temporary[document.getElementById('needs_3').value-1] = 'needs 3';
temporary[document.getElementById('needs_4').value-1] = 'needs 4';
temporary[document.getElementById('needs_5').value-1] = 'needs 5';
temporary[document.getElementById('needs_6').value-1] = 'needs 6';
```

to validate it i put a condition with the length of the array is equal to 6. that will validate the 1-6 value needed. but it cannot validate duplicate number. because if there is skipped number lets say 1,5,6 if i check the length of temporary variable it still result in 6

Comment: The approach you described will not work for detecting duplicate values or enforcing the uniqueness of the values. Instead, you can use a different approach to achieve both validation for values within the range of 1-6 and the uniqueness of values.

You can use a JavaScript Set to keep track of the unique values entered by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following way:

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" id="txt_1"><br>
  <input type="text" id="txt_2"><br>
  <input type="text" id="txt_3"><br>
  <input type="text" id="txt_4"><br>
  <input type="text" id="txt_5"><br>
  <input type="text" id="txt_6"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); //prevent the form from submitting

  let temporary = [];

  for (let i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    let inputValue = parseInt(document.getElementById(`txt_${i}`).value);

    if (!isNaN(inputValue) && inputValue >= 1 && inputValue <= 6) {
      if (temporary.includes(inputValue)) {
        alert(`Duplicate value: ${inputValue}`);
        return; //exit the function
      } else {
        temporary.push(inputValue);
      }
    } else {
      alert(`Invalid value: ${inputValue}`);
      return; //exit the function
    }
  }
  //check if you have exactly 6 values
  if (temporary.length === 6) {
    alert("Form is valid.");
    //submit the form 
  } else {
    alert("Form is invalid.");
  }
}
</script>
```

If you prefer shorter solution:

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" id="txt_1"><br>
  <input type="text" id="txt_2"><br>
  <input type="text" id="txt_3"><br>
  <input type="text" id="txt_4"><br>
  <input type="text" id="txt_5"><br>
  <input type="text" id="txt_6"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function(event) {
  
  //get all values in a number array
  let temporary = [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]')].map(el => +el.value);

  //get the size
  let allInRangeSize = arr => arr.filter(i => i >= 1 && i <= 6).length;
  let allUnique = arr => arr.length === new Set(arr).size;
  //check if unique
  if(allInRangeSize(temporary) === 6 && allUnique(temporary)){
   alert('Valid value - Form is submitting');
  }
  else{
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent the form from submitting
    alert('Invalid value');
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If my thinking is right and you just want to iterate through your form then it will be much easier to use jQuery for that because with it you will be able to perform your operation more easily on your form.

if you have a html form described by @Mamun then with jQuery you can do somrthing like this:

```
$('#myForm input').each(function () {
//this will iterate through all the input tags of your form
//you can use $(this) to perform operation on each input tag
//If you want to add value in your array you can use arr.push(value OR object)
});
```

Comment: great, @Mamun answer satisfied my needs. thank you for the alternative ways to do it thanks